# Why angular's syntax is not working in Laravel application?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

Here is the code
which I run but not working can you fix this error

```
<div ng-app="">
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>

<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
</p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you out you need to do a little more. Add all relevant code, explain what you want to achieve, what you have done and what has failed.

Comment: Did you added the required dependency angular .js files ???

Answer (score -1):

Yes your code exactly correct just you need to add the '@' before defining your variable name

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="name='abc'">
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>

<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
</p>
<h1>Hello @{{name}}</h1>

</div>
```

its working

Comment: name is not 'defined' here.